# Angular material mat-menu reloading the page

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material

So I added the simplest example of mat-menu to my project but from some reason when I click on the Menu button it is reloading the page. Here is the code.

```
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Menu</button>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
</mat-menu>
```

Comment: Is this located within a `form` element?

Comment: there just isn't enough here. that code on it's own is not going to cause this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved myself. type="button" made the trick